# Remote uploading MULTIPLE images

Tags: php, file-upload, file-get-contents, image-uploading

Okay, I have a question guys. I want to remote upload (copy an image from a site to my server) MULTIPLE images by putting links into a TEXTAREA and hitting submit. I just don't know how to make this possible with multiple images.

I am able to make it with an single image using the copy(); function, but not for multiple entries in a TEXTAREA.

I also want to limit the remote uploading feature up to 30 remote links and one image should not exceed 10MB - But I don't know how to start. I heard cURL is able to make this and I also heard that file_get_contents(); with file_put_contents(); can make a similar thing, but I still cannot figure out how to do it myself.

Help anyone? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same procedure as you do now with a single image, but do it in a loop.

```
$lines = explode("\n", $_POST['textarea']);
if(count($lines) > 30) {
  die('Too many files');
}
foreach($lines as $line) {
  $srcfile = trim($line);
  //copy $srcfile here
  //check size of the file with filesize()
}
```

Comment: I'm trying this solution. Just another question from your solution: How would I output ALL the saved images in my server with links?

Comment: I can it make it only work to GIVE me the link of the last link from all the links added, not all links.

Comment: Build an array of the links. You can add elements to the array in the foreach loop.

Answer (score 1):

You need to parse the URLs out of the `textarea`. You could with this PHP side with a regular expression.

You could then examine the parsed URLs and `array_slice()` the first 30, or error if more than 30.

You'd then need to copy the files from the remote server. You could inspect the `Content-Length` header to ensure the file is under 10mb. You could get just the headers using `HEAD` instead of `GET`.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with PHP but I suggest the following:

Solving the multiple files upload issue:

- splitting the content in the text area by the carriage return
- then iterate them to get image

preserve the size of each file in a variable, but how to get the size?

- you can do exec (system) call to know the file size (this requires a full image download but its the most convenient  way ), or you can make use of Content-Length header value, if the content length is more than 10 MG then skip it and move to the next item.

How to download the image?

- use the file put content but make sure to put the encoding as binary encoding to preserve the content type.